# laravel 5.2 project is not working on production server

Tags: php, laravel-5

Working on laravel project, facing issue on production server, my project is working on my local, but when i uploaded it on server its not responding anything , it shows blank screen, not event any error.

When i did debugging i echo things in public/index.php file and found that its not printing anything after a particular code.

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
print('Hello');
```

Afdter this code in index.php its not executing print function above this code it executes print function, it means my project is able to getting request.

I am accessing my project using

```
domain.com/public
```

I am new to laravel so don't have much understanding about this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change permissions in your server after su or after root login

chown -R:www-data path_to/storage
chmod 775 path_to/storage

And I reccomend not put your app under domain.com/public, instead point your server configuration webroot to /var/www/laravel/public